# Map displacement transformation to texture space?

Tags: mathematics, coordinates, uv-mapping, displacement-mapping

I am trying to displace geometry in object space without giving the appearance of texture warping.

My idea is to displace the UV lookup by a relative amount to the geometry displacement.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried displacing the UV look-up relative to the geometry displacement?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but maybe [Triplanar mapping](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/584/entry-2249767-tri-planar-textures-and-bump-mapping/) can get you going in the right direction.

The link might not be the best but the graphics are good and explicit, [here is another one](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33235&start=15) with code.